# Is there any OCR or technique that can recognize/identify radio buttons printed out in the form of pdf document?

Tags: python, nlp, ocr, large-language-model, information-extraction

I have a pdf document with radio responses like attached screenshot. I want to extract the selected response only through python or any OCR technique. Is there  any way of doing it?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fXu6.png)

I have tried pdfplumber,pdfminer,pytesseract but they are not able to extract the response only.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please guide me how to approach this to train mine? My end goal is to extract  ø Yes-Day Imputed  for a question/key Is this date imputed?

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for the help @KJ. I will try to extract via radio switch text.